# Data races when using mutexes

Tags: c, multithreading, image-processing

I'm working on a small project in C involving threads and mutexes. The program i'm working on applies filters on bmp mages. The goal of the project is to implement a program capable of handling this command line:

```
$ ./filter -f filter1[,filter2[,...]] -t numThreads1[,numThreads2[,...]] input-folder output-folder
```

Where -f are the filters I want to apply ("red","blue","green","grayscale" and "blur"), and -t are the numbers of threads allocated per filter.

So far everything's fine except blur, where i'm stuck on data races (or, I think so).
The blur filter work like this:

```
/* Add a Gaussian blur to an image using
* this 3X3 matrix as weights matrix:
*   0.0  0.2  0.0
*   0.2  0.2  0.2
*   0.0  0.2  0.0
*
* If we consider the red component in this image
* (every element has a value between 0 and 255)
*
*   1  2  5  2  0  3
*      -------
*   3 |2  5  1| 6  0       0.0*2 + 0.2*5 + 0.0*1 +
*     |       |
*   4 |3  6  2| 1  4   ->  0.2*3 + 0.2*6 + 0.2*2 +   ->  3.2
*     |       |
*   0 |4  0  3| 4  2       0.0*4 + 0.2*0 + 0.0*3
*      -------
*   9  6  5  0  3  9
* 
* The new value of the pixel (3, 4) is round(3.2) = 3.
*
* If a pixel is outside the image, we increment the central pixel weight by 0.2
* So the new value of pixel (0, 0) is:
*   0.2 * 0 + 0.2 * 9 + 0.2 * 6 + 0.2 * 9 + 0.2 * 9 = 6.6 -> 7
*/
```

The thing is, when I run my program on a "chessboard" image with this blur filter:

```
$ ./filter -f blur -t 8 chess.bmp chessBlur.bmp
```

I'm expecting to get this [image](http://a.yfrog.com/img12/4177/3y4.png), but i'm getting [this](http://a.yfrog.com/img690/4474/78qr.png) ("broken" lines vary randomly)

I'm using mutexes to lock and unlock the critical section, but as you can see data races still occurs.
Just two words over my filter, I give each thread a line at a time, starting from the bottom and going up.
My code for filter_blur is:

```
int filter_blur(struct image *img, int nThread)
{
    int error = 0;
    int mod = img->height%nThread;
    if (mod > 0)
        mod = 1;

    pthread_t threads[nThread];
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    args arguments[nThread];

    struct image* img2 = (struct image*)malloc(sizeof(struct image));
    memcpy(img2,img,sizeof(struct image));

    error=pthread_mutex_init( &mutex, NULL);
    if(error!=0)
        err(error,"pthread_mutex_init");

    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<nThread; i++) {
        arguments[i].img2 = img2;
        arguments[i].mutex = &mutex;
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (i=0; i<(img->height)/nThread + mod; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<nThread; j++) {

            arguments[j].img = img; arguments[j].line = i*nThread + j;

            error=pthread_create(&threads[j],NULL,threadBlur,(void*)&arguments[j]);
            if(error!=0)
                err(error,"pthread_create");
        }
        for (j=0; j<nThread; j++) {
            error=pthread_join(threads[j],NULL);
            if(error!=0)
                err(error,"pthread_join");
        }
    }
    free(img2);
    return 0;
}

void* threadBlur(void* argument) {

    // unpacking arguments
    args* image = (args*)argument;
    struct image* img = image->img;
    struct image* img2 = image->img2;
    pthread_mutex_t* mutex = image->mutex;

    int error;
    int line = image->line;
    if (line < img->height) {
        int i;

        error=pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        if(error!=0)
            fprintf(stderr,"pthread_mutex_lock");

        for (i=0; i<img->width; i++) {
            img->pixels[line * img->width +i] = blur(img2,i,line);
        }

        error=pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
        if(error!=0)
            fprintf(stderr,"pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

struct pixel blur(struct image* img2, int x, int y) {
    double red = 0;
    double green = 0;
    double blue = 0;

    red=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].r/5.0;
    green=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].g/5.0;
    blue=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].b/5.0;

    if (x != 0) {
        red+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x - 1].r/5.0;
        green+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x - 1].g/5.0;
        blue+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x - 1].b/5.0;
    } else {
        red+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].r/5.0;
        green+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].g/5.0;
        blue+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].b/5.0;
    }

    if (x != img2->width - 1) {
        red+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x + 1].r/5.0;
        green+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x + 1].g/5.0;
        blue+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x + 1].b/5.0;
    } else {
        red+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].r/5.0;
        green+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].g/5.0;
        blue+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].b/5.0;
    }

    if (y != 0) {
        red+=(double)img2->pixels[(y - 1) * img2->width + x].r/5.0;
        green+=(double)img2->pixels[(y - 1) * img2->width + x].g/5.0;
        blue+=(double)img2->pixels[(y - 1) * img2->width + x].b/5.0;
    } else {
        red+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].r/5.0;
        green+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].g/5.0;
        blue+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].b/5.0;
    }

    if (y != img2->height - 1) {
        red+=(double)img2->pixels[(y + 1) * img2->width + x].r/5.0;
        green+=(double)img2->pixels[(y + 1) * img2->width + x].g/5.0;
        blue+=(double)img2->pixels[(y + 1) * img2->width + x].b/5.0;
    } else {
        red+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].r/5.0;
        green+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].g/5.0;
        blue+=(double)img2->pixels[y * img2->width + x].b/5.0;
    }

    struct pixel pix = {(unsigned char)round(blue),(unsigned char)round(green),(unsigned char)round(red)};
    return pix;
}
```

EDIT 1 :

As @job correctly guessed, the problem was caused by memcpy of my structure (the structure was copied, but the pointers inside the structure were still pointing to the original structure elements).
I have also removed the mutexes (they were just here because I tought they could solve my problem, sorry, my bad)
Now my project is working like a charm (even if we can still discuss the processing speed, and the need to use threads). As I said, it's a project, an University project for my C class. And the goal is to parallelize our filters. So threads are needed.

Thank You!

Comment: run it with valgrind. this should help you to identificate the code that can be subject of race conditions

Comment: It seems to me that all these threads will only make the algorithm far slower. All the actual work is done inside the mutex lock, so you will have one thread working and multiple useless ones asleep.

Comment: I think, it is good idea to read data from one memory area and write blured image to new location.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something obvious here. But as far as can see img2 is a read-only copy of the original image that all the threads are reading from and then writing into different positions in the original image. Since all the threads are writing to different memory locations I don't understand why you need to synchronize them with a mutex at all. Have you tried running your code without using a mutex?

//jk

Comment: What is `struct image`? Is `pixels` an array or a pointer to dynamically allocated memory? If it is the later, then `img2` will still point into the original pixels.

Comment: @jop Yes, pixels is a pointer! Is there an easy way to create a new pixels array wich is not pointing to the original?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to `malloc` and then `memcpy` it too. There is no easy deep copy operation in C.

Comment: @jop To make deep copies makes this code even more insane. There was originally one single chunk of data that needed processing. Then the OP for reasons unknown decided to split the chunk into many, that are inefficiently processed by many threads. And now we should also add the overhead of copying and dynamic allocation? _All of this is completely pointless complexity that makes the program far slower and buggier for no gain!_

Comment: I agree this threading design isn't great, but there's an obvious question: does it work correctly when `nThread = 1`?

Comment: @Lundin Agreed. Splitting the job and then working only within the critical section is self-defeating. But the aliasing will bite even in a non-threaded version.

Comment: @Lundin Do you think that I simply need to change the architecture of this project (using threads in a more efficient way) or simply drop threads support?
Because the later is simply impossible. This project is an University project (C class, first year) and is an introduction to threads and mutexes.
If you want to take a look at the description of the project, look [here](http://sinf1252.info.ucl.ac.be/Projets/P2/enonce/) (it's in french)

Comment: @HappyRave What I would recommend is to search for information about a "design pattern" called "thread pool". A design pattern is basically just a useful program design example to solve a particular design problem, and your particular case suits the thread pool design pattern.

Comment: You need to change architecture, because at the moment you don't have parallel processing regardless of multiple threads. All your threads do their work in series, not concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you very much for your help! I managed to fix my code thanks to your answers :-)

As a fair number of comments pointed the uselessness of my mutexes, I also thought they were more like a bottleneck for my program performance than a solution to my issue.
I only added them because I hoped that they will magically fix my problem (miracles sometimes happen in programming). Now they are gone (they should have never come), and the code is faster!

Back to original problem! For the application of my blur filter, I needed a read only copy of my image. To obtain this copy, I used memcpy, like this:

```
struct image* img2 = (struct image*)malloc(sizeof(struct image));
memcpy(img2,img,sizeof(struct image));
```

But as @jop pointed this out, even if I was copying `img`, the pointer `pixels` to an allocated memory inside de copied `img2`was still pointing to the original array.
So, instead of copying `img`, copying `img->pixels` did the trick. I modified my code whith this:

```
struct pixel* pixels = (struct pixel*)malloc(sizeof(struct pixel)*img->width*img->height);
memcpy(pixels,img->pixels,sizeof(struct pixel)*img->width*img->height);
```

And voilà, problem fixed! So thank you all!

Some comments also discussed the need of using, or not threads. Well, in this case, I don't have any choice, because the goal of the project is to write some parallelized image filters. So yeah, threads needed!.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this isn't as much an answer as a number of observations regarding your code:

- You don't seem to actually access one particular memory cell from several threads anywhere in your program. So it would seem that the mutices aren't needed.
- Or alternatively, perhaps the threads do access the same memory segments. In that case, it seems very likely that your program would be far more efficient with just one single thread doing all the calculations. You should benchmark this case and compare it with the threaded version.
- At least to me, there is no apparent reason why multi-threading would be needed here. If you make those float calculations in a single thread, they are likely done before the OS has even managed to spawn a second thread. The workload is insignificant compared to the thread creation overhead time.
- Your current multi-thread design is flawed, with all the work going on inside the mutex protected code. There is no actual work that can be done outside the mutex lock, so no matter if you create 1000 threads, only 1 can execute at a time and the others will be asleep waiting for their turn.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The mutexes here were just a desperate attempt to prevent data races (my bad), which were finally caused by a bad pointer copy (I'm not totally used to all this pointers thingy with C, i'm started using C 2 months ago). Now the mutexes are gone, the pointers are corrected, and the code is working!

Comment: @HappyRave Good to hear. Instead of editing your question, you should  post the error cause and solution as a separate answer to your own question, then accept that as the correct answer. That's the proper way of sharing the info for future readers - answering your own questions is perfectly fine on SO, as long as others get a fair chance to answer it as well.

Comment: But must wait 8 hours before answering my own post because I have less than 10 reputation ...